# No Such File Or Directory Exists

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm getting the error no such file or directory exists and it is confusing the hell out of me. I don't want help filling in my methods or anything, that I want to do for myself. I want to fix this error so that I can get started on my project.

This is the error I get:
[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt0R4.png)

Here is my code where the error takes place. If you need anything else, I will gladly update my question, or provide relevant information. Thanks to anyone who helps

```
#ifndef _DLINKEDLIST_H_
#define _DLINKEDLIST_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// template class for doubly-linked list node
template <class T>
class Node
{
  public:
    T data;
    //string data;
    Node<T>* prev;
    Node<T>* next;

    // default constructor
    //template <class T>
    Node(T value)
    {
      data = value;
      prev = NULL;
      next = NULL;
    }
};

// DLinkedList class definition
template <class T>
class DLinkedList
{
  private:
    // DLinkedList private members
    int size; // number of items stored in list
    Node<T>* front; // references to the front
    Node<T>* back;  //  and back of the list

    // helper function for deep copy
    // Used by copy constructor and operator=
    void CopyList(const DLinkedList& ll);

    // helper function for deep delete
    // Used by destructor and copy/assignment
    void DeleteList();

  public:
    // default constructor
    DLinkedList();

    // copy constructor, performs deep copy of list elements
    DLinkedList(const DLinkedList& ll);

    // destructor
    ~DLinkedList();

    // MUTATORS

    // Inserts an item at the front of the list
    // POST:  List contains item at position 0
    // PARAM: item = item to be inserted
    void InsertFront(T item);

    // Inserts an item at the back of the list
    // POST:  List contains item at back
    // PARAM: item = item to be inserted
    void InsertBack(T item);

    // Inserts an item in position p (0-indexed)
    // Throws exception for invalid index
    // PRE:   0 <= p <= size
    // POST:  List contains item at position p
    // PARAM: item = item to be inserted, p = position where item will be inserted
    void InsertAt(T item, int p);

    // Removes and returns an item from position p (0-indexed)
    // Throws exception if list is empty or index invalid
    // PRE:   0 <= p < size
    // POST:  Item is removed from list
    // PARAM: p = position from where item will be removed
    T RemoveAt(int p);

    // Removes duplicates from the list, preserving existing order of remaining items.
    // The first occurrence of any duplicate (relative to the front of the list)
    //   is the one which remains.
    // We have not yet learned about efficiency so you may implement this in any way
    //   as long as the resulting list satisfies the requirement above.
    // PRE:
    // POST:  List contains no duplicates, front and back point to the appropriate nodes
    // PARAM:
    void RemoveDuplicates();

    // ACCESSORS

    // Returns size of list
    int Size() const;

    // Returns whether the list is empty
    bool IsEmpty() const;

    // Returns existence of item
    bool Contains(T item) const;

    // Returns item at index (0-indexed)
    // Throws exception for invalid index
    T ElementAt(int p) const;

    // OVERLOADED OPERATORS

    // overloaded assignment operator
    // must work in the following cases:
    // list2 = list1 -> general case
    // list2 = list2 -> should do nothing
    DLinkedList& operator=(const DLinkedList& ll);
};

#include "dlinkedlist.cpp"

#endif
```

Comment: I understand this is the code for dlinkedlist.h. Did you create also a file called dlinkedlist.cpp?

Comment: "dlinkedlist.cpp" does exist, right? And it's in the same directory as the header file?

Comment: @KenWhite yeah.  I, too, had to scan though all the header to find that include right at the end:(

Comment: I guess the OP got the .h file as part of an assignment, and has to fill in the methods. The include structure is perfectly correct.

Comment: @AndyG: OK. <Shrug> The core of the problem is still the same; the only filenames are in the #include statement, and since the error doesn't appear to be about multiple files missing it's safe to presume that the problem is with the final #include, and that the .cpp file either doesn't exist or isn't where it should be..

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick responses @CecilioPardo  I have a C++ header file, should I post here?

Comment: @KenWhite I placed it at the bottom because it is a template file. This is the way my textbook taught me to make template headers :/

Comment: @Darcy: Yes, AndyG pointed that out. I've deleted that comment. Read the one I left. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite the file exists(at least I can see it, maybe the computer can't) where should the .cpp file be?

Comment: @AndyG should I include my implementation (.cpp) file in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was a quick and easy `#include "..\srcdlinkedlist.cpp"`

instead of `#include "dlinkedlist.cpp"`